# Conditional jQuery/js addClass script

Tags: jquery, wordpress, parent, addclass

Granted I have close to none jQuery/js knowledge, I've nevertheless tried to create a short script: Wordpress outputs image classes as it follows:

```
<img class="alignleft" />
<a><img class="alignleft" /></a>
<a><img class="alignright" /></a>
```

It only add classes for the image tags, not for the  container, which leads to some limitations css side. I've

hence attempted to create a script that checks for any images with the class "alignleft/right/none" and then procedes to add a new class for the  tag.

So far I've managed to put the following piece of code together:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
wp_image = $("div.article_contents a img");

if (wp_image.hasClass ("alignleft")) {
    wp_image.parent().addClass ("wp_image alignleft")
}
else if (wp_image.hasClass ("alignright")) {
    wp_image.parent().addClass ("wp_image alignright");
}   
else (wp_image.parent().addClass ("wp_image")) {

}
});
```

The problems are:

- The first conditional statement (for the alignleft) works, but then when it comes to an "alignright" image, both "alignleft & alignright" classes are created.
- Second the last conditional statement it returns an error: as I anticipated, my jQuery knowledge is close to none and I couldn't find another way to write it down.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the whole if else statement with this:

```
if (wp_image.hasClass ("alignleft")) {
    wp_image.parent().removeClass("alignright");
    wp_image.parent().addClass("alignleft")
}
else if (wp_image.hasClass ("alignright")) {
    wp_image.parent().removeClass("alignleft");
    wp_image.parent().addClass("alignright");
}   
else{
    wp_image.parent().addClass("wp_image");
}
```

Comment: Nope, id doesn't seem to solve the problem, by replacing my code with yours the first `<img class="alignleft" />` works properly, but the following ones (an alignright and an alignnone) both get the `<a class="alignleft"></a>` class.